# Sprite menu with different background positions

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

How can we change the code to have a sprite menu with different background positions for each element?

CSS:

```
#sd_menue  { width: 266px; margin-top: 211px; float: left; }
#sd_menue li { list-style-type: none; }
#sd_menue a span { display: none; }
#sd_menue a:hover, #sd_menue a.selected { background-position: 0px -46px; }
#sd_menue a.wohnbereiche{ background-image: url('sd1.png'); }
#sd_menue a.fliesen { background-image: url('sd2.png'); }
#sd_menue a.bad { background-image: url('sd3.png'); }
#sd_menue a.kueche { background-image: url('sd4.png'); }
#sd_menue a.aussenbereich { background-image: url('sd5.png'); }
#sd_menue a.pflasterarbeiten { background-image: url('sd6.png'); }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what your trying to achieve? How are you wanting them to be different? I dont quite understand what your trying to accomplish

Comment: It will be a sidebar with a two elements sprite like on this site http://www.mooser-ingenieure.de/index.php

Comment: I have different heights per each navigation element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
#sd_menue  { width: 266px; margin-top: 211px; float: left; }
#sd_menue li { list-style-type: none; }
#sd_menue a span { display: none; }
#sd_menue a:hover, #sd_menue a.selected { 
    background:url("http://spritedatabase.net/files/gba/1032/Sprite/DonaldMugs.png") 0 5px;
}
#sd_menue a.wohnbereiche{
    background:url("http://spritedatabase.net/files/gba/1032/Sprite/DonaldMugs.png") -5px -15px;
}
```

/* The hover effect. The background position shifts over a bit.*/

```
#sd_menue a.wohnbereiche:hover{
    background:url("http://spritedatabase.net/files/gba/1032/Sprite/DonaldMugs.png") -25px -15px;

}
```

and then you'd use them like:

```
<div id='sd_menue'>
    <a class='wohnbereiche'>Link</a>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJxHa/

Comment: How to write the code so that I have a specific hover position for each element? Because in your code it would be same background position for each hover state?

Comment: Do you mean if you hover over a.fliesen that it has a different hover image then if you hover over a.bad? Just declare `a.fliesen:hover{background-position: POSITION OF IMAGE;}`

Comment: @DanielHernandez Here check this out and see if this is what you want (I used a sprite of a duck, but you can use any sprite): http://jsfiddle.net/CJxHa/

Comment: I will test it and when all is going well with that solution I will accept your answer. It would be nice if you could upvote my question. Thank you.